# Longtable: Keep the last two rows on the same page

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I know there are [similar questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117655/keeping-two-rows-on-one-page-using-longtable/117693#117693), but using `\\*` did not work for me.

What I want to achieve is that the last two rows of my table will be on the same page (and therefore no page break between them).

Please see the following example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=7.3cm,bottom=2.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}|p{1.7cm}|p{9.9cm}|p{2.6cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
        \hline
        a & \lipsum[1] & c & d\\\hline
        a & \lipsum[1] & c & d\\\hline
        a & \lipsum[1] & c & d\\\hline

        \multicolumn{1}{|l}{\textbf{Total}} & \multicolumn{3}{r|}{\bf 0} \\* \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\small I need to be just below Total}        
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which results in a page break between the last two rows.

Do you know why `\\*` isn't working? Am I using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\hline` introduces an allowed breakpoint. It is possible to drop into internals and stop that but the easiest thing to do is put the last two rows in the last foot, ie put them at the start, marked with `\endlastfoot`