# Keeping two rows on a page using xtab

Tags: tables, page-breaking, supertabular, xtab

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117655/108331) I want to have two particular rows of a table on the same page. Because my document is in `twocolumn` mode I use `xtabular`. In `longtable` the command `\\*` is supposed to work. In the following MWE the pagebreak occurs between the rows

```
2\\*
3\\
```

despite the star.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,14pt,oneside,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xtab}

\xentrystretch{-0.1}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{l}
    0\\
    1\\
    2\\
    3\\
    4\\
    5\\
    6\\
    7\\
    8\\
    9\\
    0\\
    1\\
    2\\*
    3\\
    4\\
    5\\
    6\\
    7\\
    8\\
    9\\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

`\nopagebreak` doesn't work either and I found no hint in the 'xtab' documentation.

[image: mwe]

EDIT:

`\\*` doesn't work in `supertabular` either.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add something like `\shrinkheight{<dimen>}` at appropriate spots in the table, but this requires looking at the result and guessing the good value.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,14pt,oneside,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xtab}

\xentrystretch{-0.1}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{l}
    10\\
    11\\
    12\\
    13\\
    14\\
    15\\
    16\\
    17\\
    18\\
    19\\
    20\\
    21\\\shrinkheight{-2\normalbaselineskip}
    22\\
    23\\
    24\\
    25\\
    26\\
    27\\
    28\\
    29\\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As mentioned by you this is cumbersome. Also the semantics is different to `\\*` which means something like "don't break here". `\shrinkheight{k\normalbaselineskip}` would be " put k more lines on this page/column".